# Tornado Chart/Diagram with ggplot2

Tags: r, ggplot2, histogram

I'm having a spot of difficulty getting [this](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tornado_diagram) to output right...

Here's what I've tried so far:

sample data:

```
dat <- data.frame(
variable=c("A","B","A","B"),
Level=c("Top-2","Top-2","Bottom-2","Bottom-2"),
value=c(.2,.3,-.2,-.3)
)
```

This is the closest I've got so far:

```
ggplot(dat, aes(variable, value, fill=Level)) + geom_bar(position="dodge")
## plots offset, as expected
ggplot(dat, aes(variable, value, fill=Level)) + geom_bar(position="stack") 
# or geom_bar(), default is stack but it overplots
```

Comment: This code breaks since 2012, ggplot forbids this: `Error: Mapping a variable to y and also using stat="bin" ... If you want y to represent counts of cases, use stat="bin" and don't map a variable to y.` See [ggplot2 mapping variable to y and using stat=“bin”](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15651084/ggplot2-mapping-variable-to-y-and-using-stat-bin)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Since 2012, ggplot forbids [`Error: Mapping a variable to y and also using stat="bin"`](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15651084/ggplot2-mapping-variable-to-y-and-using-stat-bin). The solution is:

```
ggplot(dat, aes(variable, value, fill=Level)) +
    geom_bar(position="identity", stat="identity")
```

It also seriously helps if you use a non-symmetric example, otherwise how do you know if you're not looking at the top series mirrored twice?!

```
dat <- data.frame(
  variable=c("A","B","A","B"),
  Level=c("Top-2","Top-2","Bottom-2","Bottom-2"),
  value=c(.8,.7,-.2,-.3)
  )
```

gives your desired tornado plot:

[image: your desired tornado plot]

Comment: Thanks for the post 2k12 answer

Comment: @BrandonBertelsen: no problem. Just trying to keep this a living breathing answer site...

Comment: It was a genuine thanks, not a fake one - if that wasn't clear. Good work!

Answer (score 2):

You could also use `+ coord_flip()` instead of `+ geom_bar(position="identity")`

Answer (score -1):

If the minus values are just a trick to compare two groups, you can use:

```
scale_y_continuous(labels=abs)
```