# Error with ggplot2 mapping variable to y and using stat="bin"

Tags: r, ggplot2

I am using ggplot2 to make a histogram:

```
geom_histogram(aes(x=...), y="..ncount../sum(..ncount..)")
```

and I get the error:

```
Mapping a variable to y and also using stat="bin".
  With stat="bin", it will attempt to set the y value to the count of cases in each group.
  This can result in unexpected behavior and will not be allowed in a future version of ggplot2.
  If you want y to represent counts of cases, use stat="bin" and don't map a variable to y.
  If you want y to represent values in the data, use stat="identity".
  See ?geom_bar for examples. (Deprecated; last used in version 0.9.2)
```

What causes this in general? I am confused about the error because I'm not mapping a variable to `y`, just histogram-ing `x` and would like the height of the histogram bar to represent a normalized fraction of the data (such that all the bar heights together sum to 100% of the data.)

*edit*: if I want to make a density plot `geom_density` instead of `geom_histogram`, do I use `..ncount../sum(..ncount..)` or `..scaled..`? I'm unclear about what `..scaled..` does.

Comment: Presumably you meant to include the `y = ` part inside `aes()`? Because that would constitute mapping `y` to a variable.

Comment: Don't wrap the call in `" "` either. `ggplot(mtcars) + geom_histogram(aes(x = mpg, y = ..count.. / sum(..count..)))` works for me.

Comment: ...and the warning (not an error!) is simply telling you to use `stat = "identity"` if you choose to map `y` to a variable. Believe me, this warning message is a _huge_ improvement over the confusion caused by `stat_bin` before the decision was made to introduce this warning. ;)

Comment: @joran: I see. are there different rules about the use of this notation for `geom_histogram` versus `geom_density`?

Comment: I blathered on more than necessary below. Since `geom_density` doesn't involve any binning, it's very unlikely you'd have mapped `y` to some other variable. But I suppose it is conceivable that you'd have to remember to either not do that, or un-map it in the density layer.

Answer (score 41, accepted):

The confusion here is a long standing one (as evidenced by the verbose warning message) that all starts with `stat_bin`.

But users don't typically realize that their confusion revolves around `stat_bin`, since they typically encounter problems while using either `geom_bar` or `geom_histogram`. Note the documentation for each: they both use `stat = "bin"` (in current **ggplot2** versions this stat has been split into `stat_bin` for continuous data and `stat_count` for discrete data) by default.

But let's back up. `geom_*`'s control the actual rendering of data into some sort of geometric form. `stat_*`'s simply transform your data. The distinction is a bit confusing in practice, because adding a layer of `stat_bin` will, by default, invoke `geom_bar` and so it can seem indistinguishable from `geom_bar` when you're learning.

In any case, consider the "bar"-like geom's: histograms and bar charts. Both are clearly going to involve some binning of data somewhere along the line. But our data could either be pre-summarised or not. For instance, we might want a bar plot from:

```
x
a
a
a
b
b
b
```

or equivalently from

```
x  y
a  3
b  3
```

The first hasn't been binned yet. The second is pre-binned. The default behavior for both `geom_bar` and `geom_histogram` is to assume that you have *not* pre-binned your data. So they will attempt to call `stat_bin` (for histograms, now `stat_count` for bar charts) on your `x` values.

As the warning says, it will then try to map `y` for you to the resulting counts. If you *also* attempt to map `y` yourself to some other variable you end up in Here There Be Dragons territory. Mapping `y` to functions of the variables returned by `stat_bin` (`..count..`, etc.) should be ok and should not throw that warning (it doesn't for me using @mnel's example above).

The take-away here is that for `geom_bar` if you've pre-computed the heights of the bars, always remember to use `stat = "identity"`, or better yet use the newer `geom_col` which uses `stat = "identity"` by default. For `geom_histogram` it's very unlikely that you will have pre-computed the bins, so in most cases you just need to remember not to map `y` to anything beyond what's returned from `stat_bin`.

`geom_dotplot` uses it's own binning stat, `stat_bindot`, and this discussion applies here as well, I believe. This sort of thing generally hasn't been an issue with the 2d binning cases (`geom_bin2d` and `geom_hex`) since there hasn't been as much flexibility available in the analogous `z` variable to the binned `y` variable in the 1d case. If future updates start allowing more fancy manipulations of the 2d binning cases this could I suppose become something you have to watch out for there.

Answer (score 8):

The documentation for `geom_histogram` states that it is an alias for `stat_bin` and `geom_bar`

The documentation for `geom_density` states that uses a smooth density estimate produced using `stat_density`

Following the links (or finding the help pages directly)

#### `stat_bin`

The documentation for `stat_bin` describes how `stat_bin` returns a data.frame with the following (additional) columns

> **count**  number of points in bin
>
> **density**    density of points in bin, scaled to integrate to 1
>
> **ncount**     count, scaled to maximum of 1
>
> **ndensity**   density, scaled to maximum of 1

#### `stat_density`

The documentation for `stat_density` describes how `stat_density` returns a data.frame with the following (additional) columns

> **density**    density estimate
>
> **count**  density * number of points - useful for stacked density plots
>
> **scaled**     density estimate, scaled to maximum of 1

---

To produce a plot on the same scale it would appear that you want `..ndensity..` from `stat_bin` and `..scaled..` from `stat_density` or `..density..` from both

```
ggplot(dd, aes(x=x)) + 
  geom_histogram(aes(y= ..density..)) +  
  geom_density(aes(y=..density..))


ggplot(dd, aes(x=x)) + 
  geom_histogram(aes(y= ..ndensity..)) + 
  geom_density(aes(y=..scaled..))
```

Comment: Can you please explain the difference between these four calls: `geom_density(aes(x='myvar'))` versus `geom_density(aes(x='myvar', y='..density..'))` versus `geom_density(aes(x='myvar', y='..scaled..'))` versus `geom_density(aes(x='myvar', y='..count../sum(..count..)'))`? moving to different thread so it's not messy