# How to interpret the different ggplot2 densities?

Tags: r, ggplot2

I am confused about the meaning of the following variants of `geom_density` in ggplot:

Can someone please explain the difference between these four calls:

1. `geom_density(aes_string(x=myvar))`
2. `geom_density(aes_string(x=myvar, y=..density..))`
3. `geom_density(aes_string(x=myvar, y=..scaled..))`
4. `geom_density(aes_string(x=myvar, y=..count../sum(..count..)))`

My understanding is that:

- `geom_density` alone will produce a density whose area under the curve sums to 1
- `geom_density` with `..density..` basically does the same... ?
- the `..count../sum(..count..)` will normalize the peak heights to be more like a normalized histogram, ensuring that all the heights sum to 1
- the `..count..` by itself without the denominator will just multiply each bin by # of items in it
- the `..scaled..` parameter will make it so the maximum value of the density is 1.

I find `..scaled..` very counterintuitive and have never seen it used if my interpretation of it is correct so I'd like to ignore that. I am mainly looking for a clarification of the differences between `geom_density` and a kind of normalized density plot, which I am assuming requires the `...count../...` argument. thanks.

(Related: [Error with ggplot2 mapping variable to y and using stat="bin"](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15651084/ggplot2-mapping-variable-to-y-and-using-stat-bin))

Comment: Unrelated: you really need to stop quoting the variables inside `aes()`. Unless you're using `aes_string` you shouldn't be doing that.

Comment: @joran: I am using `aes_string`, sorry, I am using rpy2 so it's always `aes_string`

Comment: Just to readers who are wondering. The question has been edited to fix the concerns with `aes` vs. `aes_string`. This error was not central to the question.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

The default aesthetic for `stat_density` is `..density..`, so a call to `geom_density` which uses `stat_density` by default, will plot `y = ..density..` by default.

You can see how the various columns are caculated by looking at the [source code](https://github.com/hadley/ggplot2/blob/master/R/stat-density.r)

`..scaled..` is defined as

```
densdf$scaled <- densdf$y / max(densdf$y, na.rm = TRUE)
```

Feel free to ignore it if you wish.

Looking at the [source code for stat_bin](https://github.com/hadley/ggplot2/blob/master/R/stat-bin.r)

The results are computed as such

```
res <- within(results, {
    count[is.na(count)] <- 0
    density <- count / width / sum(abs(count), na.rm=TRUE)
    ncount <- count / max(abs(count), na.rm=TRUE)
    ndensity <- density / max(abs(density), na.rm=TRUE)
  })
```

So if you want to compare the results of `geom_histogram` (using the default `stat = 'bin'`), then you can set `y = ..density..` and it will calculate `count / sum(count)` for you (accounting for the width of the bins)

If you wanted to compare `geom_density(aes(y=..scaled..))` with `stat_bin`, then you would use `geom_histogram(aes(y = ..ndensity..))`

You could get them on the same scale by using `..count..` in both as well, however you would need to adjust the `adjust` parameter in `stat_density` to get the appropriately detailed approximation of the curve.