# ggplot2 - geom_histogram / scale_fill_manual

Tags: r, ggplot2

I am working the following dataframe (df):

```
df$GP<-c(0,0,0,1,1,2,3,3,3,3,4,4,9,15,18,18,19,19,20,20,21,22,22,23)
```

`df$colour<-c("g","g","g","g","g","g","g","g","g","g","g","g","t","t","g","g","g","g","g","g","g","g","g","g")`

I want the histogram below, but showing a different fill for `colour=="g"` and `colour=="t"`. 
[image: plot]
However, running the following code, the bars labelled `colour=="t"`, go out of scale (up to 1 - plot2) whereas should be at 0.25 (plot1).

```
ggplot(data=df,aes(x=GP,y=..ndensity..))+geom_histogram(bins=25,aes(fill=colour))+scale_fill_manual(values=c("black","grey"))
```

[image: plot2]

Do you have any idea of how this could be achieved?

Thank you very much for your help with this one!

Comment: Please take a look [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15664202/how-to-interpret-the-different-ggplot2-densities/15672594#15672594) for an explanation of densities and scales.

Answer (score 1):

I used a tibble as the data type for dataset, with different tibble variable names.

the result is just as you want.

```
  tb <- tibble(
  tbx = c(0, 0, 0, 1, 1, 2, 3, 3, 3, 3, 4, 4, 9, 15, 18, 18, 19, 19, 20, 20, 21, 22, 22, 23),
  tby = c("g","g","g","g","g","g","g","g","g","g","g","g","t","t","g","g","g","g","g","g","g","g","g","g")
)


ggplot(tb, aes(tbx, tby = ..ndensity..)) +
  geom_histogram(bins = 25, aes(fill = tby)) +
  scale_fill_manual(values = c("red", "grey"))
```

and this is the output plot: 
[image: Output Plot]

I hope this addresses your question

Comment: Dear Yusuf, thank you for your answer! Actually, I already managed to obtain your output, having counts on the y.axis. However, I would like to have the same result but with density scaled to 1 (as in the plot I posted before). I can imagine that, when I do that, the two values labelled with "t", are treated as a separate dataset. Therefore, density is scaled to 1 for both entries (like in plot 2, in my post). Not sure if this make any sense...Thank you again!

Comment: actually I didn't get what do you mean with your words:

I want the histogram below, but showing a different fill for `colour=="g" and colour=="t".`

Comment: What I meant was: I would exactly the same graph as yours, but with density (form 0 to 1) in the y.axis instead of "count"

Comment: may you write down your full code here to have look at it
@matbess