# ggplot2 Error : Mapping a variable to y and also using stat="bin". example from 'Elegant Graphics for Data Analysis'

Tags: r, graphics, plot, ggplot2

I'm trying to learn `ggplot2` to apply it to my own data, but have encountered a problem when trying to reproduce a plot from the book 'Elegant Graphics for Data Analysis' by Hadley Wickham (Fig 4.10 (right), chapter 4: 4.9.1 Combining geoms and stats, p. 61) using the following code:

```
d <- ggplot(diamonds, aes(carat)) + xlim(0, 3)
d + stat_bin(aes(y = 1, fill = ..count..), binwidth = 0.1, geom = "tile", position="identity")
```

It results in the following error message:

```
# Error : Mapping a variable to y and also using stat="bin".
# With stat="bin", it will attempt to set the y value to the count of cases in each group.
# This can result in unexpected behavior and will not be allowed in a future version of ggplot2. 
# If you want y to represent counts of cases, use stat="bin" and don't map a variable to y. 
# If you want y to represent values in the data, use stat="identity".
# See ?geom_bar for examples. (Defunct; last used in version 0.9.2)
```

How can I reproduce the desired plot/fix the error? Could you please explain it bit if possible. How could the same kind of plot be produced using `geom_tile`?

Thank you very much for your help!!

Comment: I'm using OSX 10.9.4; R Studio Version 0.98.507; ggplot2 version 1.0.0

Comment: For a more thorough handling of the specific error, you may have a look at [**this nice Q&A**](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15651084/ggplot2-mapping-variable-to-y-and-using-stat-bin)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The same error is produced when running the equivalent examples in `?geom_tile`, e.g. `cars + stat_bin(aes(fill=..count..), geom="tile", binwidth=3, position="identity")`. The output is still found [**here**](http://docs.ggplot2.org/current/geom_tile.html) though, also showing what I assume was the *warning* message in older `ggplot2` versions.

One possible solution would be to use `stat_bin2d`, with a dummy y variable, and use the `binwidth` argument. The first number in the `binwidth` vector (`c(0.1, 1)`) refers to x values and the second to the y values. `binwidth` is not documented in the 'Arguments' section in the help text, but can be found among [**the examples**](http://docs.ggplot2.org/current/stat_bin2d.html)

```
ggplot(diamonds, aes(x = carat, y = factor(1))) + xlim(0, 3) +
  stat_bin2d(binwidth = c(0.1, 1))
```

[image]

**Update**: For a more thorough account of the error message, see [**this nice Q&A**](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15651084/ggplot2-mapping-variable-to-y-and-using-stat-bin)

Answer (score 0):

please refer to:
[Error with ggplot2 mapping variable to y and using stat="bin"](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15651084/ggplot2-mapping-variable-to-y-and-using-stat-bin?lq=1)

based on my experience, for ggplot2 version 0.92, there is only warnings for geom_bar() without default stat parameter. but for version 1.0.0, it will end with error. If you specify stat="identity" for bar plot using geom_bar.