# ggplot2 warning: Stacking not well defined when not anchored on the axis

Tags: r, ggplot2

I'm trying different ways of reproducing a graphic in fig 4.10 of Wickham's Elegant Graphics for Data Analysis, since the code in the book no longer works (I'm using ggplot2 3.1.0).  I have something that seems to work but its producing a warning message and I want to know what that is all about.

I've looked at some relevant posts but they do not answer my specific question ([ggplot2 Error : Mapping a variable to y and also using stat="bin". example from 'Elegant Graphics for Data Analysis'](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24628254/ggplot2-error-mapping-a-variable-to-y-and-also-using-stat-bin-example-from)) The graphic I produce seems to work I just need info on what the warning is all about.

```
##this is whats in the book, it doesn't work because of the y variable in the 
##aes()
d <- ggplot(diamonds, aes(carat)) + xlim(0, 3)
d + stat_bin(aes(y = 1, fill = ..count..), binwidth = 0.1, geom = "tile", position="identity")


##My reaction was to just cut out the variable and instead change position to 
##"fill"
d + stat_bin(
    aes(fill = ..count..), binwidth = 0.1,
    geom = "tile", position="fill")
```

The graphic looks right, but the following warning is given:
Stacking not well defined when not anchored on the axis

What does this mean and is it a concern in my case?  When would it be a concern?

---Edit---
I want to clarify that I a specifically asking about the error using this specific method.  I can produce the same graphic using other methods that do not give me the warning.

--Edit--
Here is some code that produces the graphic I would like. I looks exactly like the one I produce above, but does not give me the warning: Stacking not well defined when not anchored on the axis

```
d <- ggplot(diamonds, aes(carat)) + xlim(0, 3)
d + geom_histogram(
    aes(fill = ..count..), binwidth = 0.1,
    position="fill")
```

Comment: Can you post a link to the graphic you're trying to produce?

Comment: @Gregor I just added an edit that addresses your comment

Comment: [Here's](https://i.imgur.com/voU8hjN.png) an image of Figure 4.10 from the 1st ed. of ggplot2.  Is this what you were going for?  It differs substantially from the example you gave.

Comment: @RaoulDuke thanks for the figure.  I'm not too concerned about exact reproduction which is why I ignored the color scheme.  As for the y-axis, I'm unsure why the original scales to something larger than 1, from context I assumed it was a "typo" of sorts.  In my next edit I clarify that I can produce a graphic I want, but am curious why the other method gives me the same looking graphic with a warning.

Answer (score 0):

I found a stupid way to solve this question.
To avoid the wrong position of errobar, I plot errobar twice.

##data

```
test_2
ID  type    value
cu  s   0.2814644
cu  s   0.278847685
cu  s   0.1909515
cu  t   
cu  t   
cu  t   
Bu  b   12.70410914
Bu  b   13.2930925
Bu  b   14.43481323

test_3
ID  type    value
Bu  s   
Bu  s   
Bu  b   
cu  t   11.71781248
cu  t   11.55618308
cu  t   12.91048587
```

##code

```
> d1$type <- factor(d1$type, levels =c("b", "t", "s")) ggplot(d1,
> aes(ID,  value , fill = type)) +   theme_bw() +   stat_summary(
>     geom = "col",
>     fun = "mean",
>     position = "stack",
>     width = 0.6,
>     col = "black",
>     size = 1   ) +   stat_summary(
>     data = d2,
>     geom = "errorbar",
>     fun.min = function(x)
>       mean(x) - sd(x),
>     fun.max = function(x)
>       mean(x) + sd(x),
>     position = "identity",
>     width = 0.1,
>     size = 1   ) +   stat_summary(
>     data = d3,
>     geom = "errorbar",
>     fun.min = function(x)
>       mean(x) - sd(x)+0.25,
>     fun.max = function(x)
>       mean(x) + sd(x)+0.25,
>     position = "identity",
>     width = 0.1,
>     size = 1   )
```

[image]

Comment: Please provide additional details in your answer. As it's currently written, it's hard to understand your solution.